# How do I set the dataprovider for one dropdown list, based on another in the same row?

Tags: apache-flex, drop-down-menu, datagrid, flex4, flex-spark

I have an editable flex spark datagrid with two columns.  Parameters and Values.
I have been asked to change the datagrid, such that the first column of Parameters, can only be set to a value which comes from a set datalist.

The second column of Values, must also be set to a discrete value based on a drop down box, which is based on the value in the Parameters Column.

How do I set the dataproviders for the Values column, such that it's dependent on the selected item in the Parameter Column?

**Note, the code provided here is simplified, in my actual code, I have the item renders set as different classes. But if I have to do it this way to make the data available, I'll do it inline.

```
<s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn minWidth="100" dataField="parameter" headerText="Parameter"  rendererIsEditable="true">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:GridItemRenderer>
                            <fx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[
                                import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

                                protected function onParamDropListChange(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {
                                    var value:String = (event.currentTarget as DropDownList).selectedItem;
                                    data[column.dataField] = value;
                                                                       }
                                ]]>
                    </fx:Script>

                            <s:DropDownList id="paramDownList" requireSelection="true" width="100%"
                                            labelField="name"    
                                            dataProvider="{outerDocument.loadedParamList}"
                                            change="onParamDropListChange(event)">
                            </s:DropDownList>

                        </s:GridItemRenderer>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>
            </s:GridColumn>


            <s:GridColumn minWidth="200" dataField="value" headerText="Value"  rendererIsEditable="true">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:GridItemRenderer>
                            <fx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[
                                import spark.components.DataGrid;
                                import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

                                protected function onValueDropListChange(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {
                                    var value:String = (event.currentTarget as DropDownList).selectedItem;
                                    data[column.dataField] = value;
                                }

                                ]]>
                    </fx:Script>

                            <s:DropDownList id="ValueDownList" requireSelection="true" width="100%"
                                            labelField="values"
                                           dataProvider="{SOME_REFERENCE_TO_THE_PARAM_COLUMN_VALUE}"
                                            change="onValueDropListChange(event)">
                            </s:DropDownList>

                        </s:GridItemRenderer>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>
```

Here is an example of the Parameters and their possible values.

```
    {"params": [
    {"name": "event_group",         "values": ["CLIENTS", "SERVERS"]},
    {"name": "event_sub_group",     "values": ["LOADING", "MACHINE_LOADING"]},
    {"name": "environment",         "values": ["stage", "production"]}
    ]
    }
```

So if the user selects "event_group" on one row of the Params column, I want the user to only to be able to select "CLIENTS" or "SERVERS" on that same row, in the Values Column.  Once selected, the value would then be updated and propagated up to the relevant object.

Answer (score 1):

So this is an idea that I would try it first if I would have to solve this,so I am not sure if it will work.(it may need some work)

I am thinking that you could create a class that will represnetthe data you want to show in the datagrid. So this class will have 2 fields of type ArrayCollection that you bind them to the dropdowns.
When the users changes  some dropdowns the underling data is updated and this will trigger the datagrid updates. 
So my idea is to split your code in 2 parts the View and the Model ,

```
class MyData{
//you dhould make all fields bindable
public var selectedParam:String;
public var selectedValue:String;
public var allParams:ArrayCollection;
public var allValues:ArrayCollection;
//call this method  when selectedParam is changed (you should make it a getter/setter and call update in the setter)
function updateValues():void{
    //update the allValues  by checking the selectedParam
}
}
```

EDIT:
When you set the selectedParam then you trigger the updateValues that will populate the allValues collection with the correct values(you generate them or if the possible values are from a Set you can replace the current ArrayCollection with the correct one)
EDIT2:
You create an instance of this class for each row and add it in an ArrayCollection then set the ArrayCollection as dataProvider for the grid.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like I didn't make the relationship clear.  Each set of Params, has an array of possible values.
Even if I modified this, how would I return the list of values for the selected param to the dataprovider or each row?

Comment: I must be missing something. How do I set an instance of this class to each row?